# Easiest way to calculate how deep a structure is?

Tags: python, data-structures, abstract-syntax-tree

Let say I have a AST-structure (a list of lists) like this one :

```
 [+, [*, a,b],[*,c,d] ]
 [+, [*, a,b],[*,c,[ +, d, e] ] ]
```

what is the easiest and/or fastest way to calculate how deep the structure is i.e. how many levels it is ?

As a second option you could also work with it as a String, rather than List-of-Lists (LoL). F.e.:

```
"[+, [*, a,b],[*,c,d] ]"
```

I could use both.

Comment: Traverse the string and keep track of the depth by counting `[` and `]`.

Comment: FYI: From experience, I highly recommend using objects over lists/tuples to represent an abstract syntax tree. Using the latter is fragile, and the former offers a much more convenient interface.

Comment: A way would be to represent your structure with a graph and apply graph-based algorithms (e.g. DFS etc...) - but graph theory is a huge topic and your question is very general (e.g. do you want to count cycles, etc...)

Answer (score 3):

You can keep the count of the square brackets.
You can find a more detailed explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45982748/7051394).
Here is an adaptation of the code:

```
string = str(tree)

currentDepth = 0
maxDepth = 0
for c in string:
    if c == '[':
        currentDepth += 1
    elif c == ']':
        currentDepth -= 1

    maxDepth = max(maxDepth, currentDepth)
```

Same caveat, this will break if your data might contain `'['` or `']'`.
In such case, you'll need to define an escape method for those square brackets.